# Checking array for object before updating it in redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Does anyone know how to check if an object is inside an array, and if so, update it?

I tried the find method but when I do, it says it can't find the object I'm referring to. I also tried includes but for some reason it too doesn't think the item is in the array.

This is the best I got:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface Displate {
  name: string;
  finish: string;
  size: string;
  frame: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
}

interface DisplateArray extends Array<Displate> {}

const initialState: DisplateArray = [];

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<Displate>) => {
      state.map((displate) => {
        if (displate.name === action.payload.name) {
          return displate.quantity++;
        } else {
          return state.push(action.payload);
        }
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { addDisplate } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

But this just adds a new object everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `quantity` is not updated because `state.map` does not mutate the updated `quantity` back to the proxy `state` for an update.

Assuming that the goal is to check item with same `name` in the state array, if item exists add 1 to its `quantity`, and if not add a new object from`action.payload` to the array, consider to use `find` as a condition instead (using Immer update from Redux Toolkit):

```
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<Displate>) => {
      const existingItem = state.find(
        (item) => item.name === action.payload.name
      );
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
        return;
      }
      existingItem.quantity++;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This works thanks! How would you remove an item btw? Assuming the payload was a string? state.filter(item => item.name !== action.payload)?

Comment: @ether Thanks for the feedback, for removing I think first check `existingItem.quantity` and do `existingItem.quantity--` if `.quantity` is more than 1, or if `quantity` is at 1 then do `state = state.filter((item) => item.name !== action.payload.name)` to remove the item should work.